# TypeScript cannot pass component as prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jsx

I am using Next.js with TypeScript. I have an array of items that I loop over and display in my HTML. I am getting the error below when I pass in my component named "InboxIcon" as JSX in my array of items like:

❌ This doens't work... It causes the errror

```
const features = [
    {        
        title: 'hello'
        icon: <InboxIcon strokeWidth={6}/>        
    },
]
```

> Server Error Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
> built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
> but got: object.
>
> This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will
> be displayed in the terminal window. Call Stack renderElement

✅ This works

```
const features = [
    {        
        title: 'hello'
        icon: InboxIcon
    },
]
```

How can I get the first way of doing this to work?

**index.tsx**

```
import { ItemColumnOne } from '@/components/Card'
import { InboxIcon } from '@/components/InboxIcon'

const features = [
    {        
        title: 'hello'
        icon: <InboxIcon strokeWidth={6}/>        
    },
]

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <>
            {features.map((feature) => (
            <Card
                    key={feature.title}
                    icon={feature.icon}                                        
                />
            ))}
        </>
)
```

**Card.tsx**

```
interface Props {
    title: string    
    icon: any
}

export function Card(props: Props) {
    return (
        <div>                           
            <props.icon className="display-icon"/>                                                                                                                    
            {props.title}
        </div>
    )
}
```

**InboxIcon**

```
interface Props {
    className?: string
    strokeWidth: number
}

export function InboxIcon(props: Props) {
    return (
        <svg
            className={props.className}
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 512 512"
            aria-hidden="true"
        >            
            <path                
                strokeWidth={props.strokeWidth}                
                fill="currentColor"                
                d="M 70 110 C 70 140, 110 140, 110 110"
            />
        </svg>
    )
}
```

Comment: To do the first way, render `<div>{props.icon}{props.title}</div>`

Comment: That worked but I would like to set some default html classes on the icon from the card component and if i did it this way I wouldn't be able to set classes @NicholasTower

like `` <props.icon className="inbox-icon-styles"/>``

Comment: I know I can wrap the icon in a div and put the class on the div, but I want the class to be on the icon itself

Answer (score 0):

In terms of Function Components, this line:

```
<InboxIcon strokeWidth={6}/>
```

is equivalent to:

```
InboxIcon({strokeWidth: 6});
```

and this line:

```
<props.icon className="display-icon"/>
```

is equivalent to:

```
props.icon({className: "display-icon"})
```

So in the most basic form you're trying to do this:

```
// This returns a component, which is an object
const icon = InboxIcon({strokeWidth: 6}); 

// You're trying to call an object like a function
icon({className: "display-icon"})
```

Hence the error: "Element is invalid ... got: object".

Hopefully you can see why that doesn't work.

---

Lucky for you, React provides a convenient way to add properties to an existing component: [`cloneElement`](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement)

```
export function Card(props: Props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {cloneElement(props.icon, {className: "display-icon"})}                                                                                                                                  
            {props.title}
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
const features = [
    {        
        title: 'hello'
        icon: <InboxIcon strokeWidth={6}/>        
    },
]
```

---

**Stackblitz Typescript Example:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-6ufs9e?file=index.tsx

---

**Snippet JavaScript Example**

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(<Home />);

const features = [
  {
    title: 'hello',
    icon: <InboxIcon strokeWidth={6} />,
  },
];

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      {features.map((feature) => (
        <Card key={feature.title} title={feature.title} icon={feature.icon} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function Card(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {React.cloneElement(props.icon, { className: 'display-icon' })}
      {props.title}
    </div>
  );
}

function InboxIcon(props) {
  return (
    <svg
      className={props.className}
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 512 512"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <path
        strokeWidth={props.strokeWidth}
        fill="currentColor"
        d="M 70 110 C 70 140, 110 140, 110 110"
      />
    </svg>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```